# Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

The title is a duplicate but my question is different.

The same project works fine and is allowed to be built on

> buildToolsVersion 23.0.3

on my colleague's system. As far as I know only the android studio version is different.
Is it possible that if I hadn't upgraded my android studio to "2.3.Beta 2"
I could still build with 23.0.3?

Comment: post your module level build file

Comment: Would you be so kind to mark my answer as a correct one?

Comment: @isabsent yeah I did,I'm sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You have to change **top-level** *build.gradle* from

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
//        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

to:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
//        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3` also solved my problem when trying to compile `react-native-mail` 

Comment: 2.3.0 is a new gradle plugin and it is supposed to work with buildToolsVersion 25 or higher. If you change gradle plugin version to 2.2.3 you get possibility to work with old buildToolsVersion 23.0.3.

Comment: How come this answer is not marked as correct answer yet ?!

Answer (score 5):

Ok I found a solution to this.

For people facing the same problem in the future, here's what I did:

I added the following to my root build gradle android/build.gradle
(Not the android/app/build.gradle)

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 25
                buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That forces all the submodules to use the specified compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion.
Problem gone now.

Answer (score 3):

> if I hadn't upgraded my android studio to "2.3.Beta 2" I could still build with 23.0.3?

Yes.

You can still run the build process from command line with any version of build tools.

Feel free to upgrade build tools to 25.0.2 (latest as of 27.1.2017). **This only affects build process, it doesn't affect the app behavior.**

Newer versions of build tools incorporate more options and newer technologies and newer versions of Android Studio depend on these technologies.

Comment: I am trying to run with 23.0.3 but it keeps showing the above mentioned error and refuses to compile. I have all sdk versions downloaded till date. Why is the studio preventing me from running in 23? I am just trying to figure out whether it has anything to do with the studio update

Comment: Yes, but that's a fact not the question.

Comment: Building with 25 gives me an error
/* java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. */
With 23 none of my colleagues are getting that error.
Same project,same code.
That's the reason Im confused

Comment: That's after building and running so unrelated to original question. Do what it says! Thats one of the most helpful messages!

Comment: Why is the studio preventing me from running in 23?
It's a question.
By the way, next time I want to upgrade my development tools, please sedate me.

Comment: @GiorgioBarchiesi what version of AS? 23 of what? Always be specific when asking for help.

Comment: Android Studio 2.3, API 23, Build Tools Version was 23.0.3 (but AS wants 25), min sdk version 16, target sdk version 23.

Comment: You *want* latest build tools. Is I mentioned they make the build process harder, better, faster, stronger. They don't affect how the app behaves. And modern versions of AS require modern versions of Android build tools. And Android build plugin. And Gradle. To make the build process more effective and provide you with more options (such as Instant Run). Don't fight it :D

Comment: My problem was with the "Dependencies" tab of the "Project Structure". It only lists version 25 libraries; I had to manually specify "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1" and "com.android.support.design:23.2.1"

Comment: Change back `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3` in the **top-level** *build.gradle*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can do
2.3 studio is upto 25 supported you want to install sdk 19to25 in studio

Comment: Upto 25 right? So I should be able to build with 23. Why is it preventing me from running on 23?That's what I wanna know.

Answer (score 0):

Setting classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+' can resolve my problem when my project migrated from Android Studio 1.5.0 to 2.3.0.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue:

added this code in `android/build.gradle`

```

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```